# Why my changes of AppSettings in App.config is not taken into account in run-time? (Console Application)

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, configurationmanager

I have a console application which has its own App.config.

I need to change some values in  section time to time.

My problem is, when I execute the exe within the bin/debug folder it gets the relevant appsettings correctly. But when I edit and change values of some key/value pairs and RE-RUN the exe, it still reads the original values.

(By RE-RUN I mean running the application on the command promt by calling MyTool.exe)

I tried to call

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

in the begining of my Main method. But did not help.

Can you please advise?
Thanks

Comment: Do you edit the app.config inside the IDE or do you edit directly the exe.config in the BIN/DEBUG folder?

Comment: In the debug folder. Not in the IDE.

Comment: And what is the value on the property Copy to output directory of your app.config inside the IDE?

Comment: Just hitting F5 after any changes in code wont do it. Just rebuild and then hit F5 for the new values in app.config to updated in the *.config file under the `bin\debug` folder

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> But when I edit and change values of some key/value pairs and RE-RUN
>   the exe, it still reads the original values.

Depends how you are RE-RUNNing this exe. If you are doing this in Visual Studio, by hitting <kbd>F5</kbd>, VS simply copies the app.config file in your project to the output and renames it to `AppName.exe.config`. So if you want your changes to be taken into account you have to modify `AppName.exe.config` (not `App.config`) and then run the executable from the Windows Explorer.

This being said, the App.config is read and parsed only once. When the application starts. The values are then cached to avoid expensive XML parsing everytime your application requests some value.

App.config is designed to store configuration values that are not supposed to be changed. If you need to change configuration values dynamically you should use some other storage mechanism: file, database, ...

But the `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");` method should work. Once you have modified the `AppName.exe.config` file, you call this method and then refetch the value you need using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someKey"];` which should return you the new value.

Comment: I agree. But what if I would nee do achieve what I asked for. Is it possible? (+1 for the best practice advise)

Comment: By RE-RUN I mean running the application on the command promt by calling MyTool.exe

Comment: Who is going to modify this file while the application is running? The application itself or some other external process?

Comment: Users. Basicaly 2-3 people, on their local machines in case it is necessary.

Comment: In this case the `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");` method should work. But I don't recommend going that route.

Comment: Ok. I found the problem, it is my bad. The output directory has both App.Config and MyApp.exe.config. I was modifying App.config instead. Thanks for mentioning it :)

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: Also worth mentioning if you are running under debugger in Visual Studio, you will need to update `MyApp.vshost.exe.config` in the bin folder, and open the correct build path (e.g. Debug, Release, etc).  

Noting this because I had an "I'm dumb" moment.

Comment: Had this issue come up today, make sure you set App.config Properties "Copy To Output Directory" to "Do not copy", that way you will not get two config files in the bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to manually delete the application.exe.config located in /obj/Debug/ as this was basically acting like a cache.  So anytime I would edit my app.config, (re)build, but looked at the application.exe.config, it was not fully updated after the build.  Doing the above allowed me to force the IDE to recreate the application.exe.config in the /bin/

Answer (score 0):

```
  Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
// change ConnectionString in App.Config for Entity FrameWork Object....
 //..... 
config.Save();
```

are you save config file?