# how to refresh/reload app.config file before a function or method executes

Tags: c#, windows-services, app-config, configuration-files, configurationmanager

I have a windows service that send out emails at a particular hour of the a particular day. The and hour on when the email should be send out along with information like the SMTP server to use are stored in the app.config file.

When i open the app.config file in notepad and change those values, my service does not pick the changes even when i call `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("configuration");`

How can i make sure that every time my email sending function executes, it must first query the app.config for the latest changes/values. Must i restart the service first?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the app.config, try modifying the appname.exe.config file with this refresh section.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466965/why-my-changes-of-appsettings-in-app-config-is-not-taken-into-account-in-run-tim). Hope it helps. Thanks