# C# Entity Framework Reconnecting to the database by new connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

1 Run Application
2. Create Context

```
dbContext = new DBFirstContext();
```

3 Change App.config connection string for Entity FrameWork Object

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
// change ConnectionString in App.Config for Entity FrameWork Object....
//.....
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

4. And now if I create

   ```
   dbContext = new DBFirstContext();
   ```

   It use sourse unchanged connectionString, as it was at starting application. If Close and then restart the application - new dbContext will be created by using modified connectionString.

PS: I don't want to passing new connection string for create new dbContext by using constructor like this:

```
public DBFirstContext(string sConnectionString)
        : base(sConnectionString)
```

I need to create dbContext by using default constructor, and that it take a new (changed) connection string from the app.config  without restarting the application. Is it possible?

Thank!

Answer (score 3):

The App.config is read and parsed only once.

See the answer of "Darin Dimitrov" that was marked as the final answer. [Why my changes of AppSettings in App.config is not taken into account in run-time? (Console Application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466965/why-my-changes-of-appsettings-in-app-config-is-not-taken-into-account-in-run-tim)

I only take credit for Googling for this answer. All other credit should go to Darin.

In short: you're trying to use someting in a way it's not meant to be used. What is the reason you only want to work with the default constructor?

Comment: It is simple, the Application almost is ready, and everywhere were used default constructor for create dbContext, now i need to create option form, where user may custom connection to Data Base...PS:If I restart the application - the configuration file is saved

Comment: Based on the feedback what you're trying isn't "correct" so to speak.
You should create a function that accepts the parameters (indicating the user selection for that "custom connection") to then create your database connection.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you need to change app.config or your connection string at runtime, but one way to change the connection string of your context without reconstructing it, is the following:

```
context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "connection string here";
```

Of course, your connection string must respect the format required by EF, so one way to construct your connection string is:

```
 String.Format(
@"metadata=res://*/DBFirstContext.csdl|res://*/DBFirstContext.ssdl|res://*/DBFirstContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='{0}'", connString);
```

where connString is a [SQL Server connection string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#sqlserver)

Answer (score 0):

my solution How to use default constructor for create context object by using connectionString from curent App.Config (App.Config were edited at run-time)

```
        public DBFirstContext()
        : base(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBFirstContext"].ConnectionString)
    {
    }
```