# Console application is not taking config values from its config file after deployment

Tags: c#, console-application, app-config, application-settings

In my console application,it has application settings created and also has app.config file.

After build I get appname.exe and appname.exe.config (it has test configuration values).

when I deploy these files on production and change some entries in appname.exe.config according to Production and run the application via scheduler.

it still gets test configuration values somehow, is there something I messed up with the configuration values. for me it looks like somehow appname.exe has taken the entries from application settings and not loading appname.exe.config

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my changes of AppSettings in App.config is not taken into account in run-time? (Console Application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466965/why-my-changes-of-appsettings-in-app-config-is-not-taken-into-account-in-run-tim)

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, if you are using the *Settings* UI in *Visual Studio* to setup your configuration...

- `Settings` are stored within the application's configuration file `appname.exe.config`
- these settings also have a corresponding default value that are embedded within the application

  - the default value is what you type into the *Settings* UI
- if the configuration values cannot be read from the `appname.exe.config`, then the default values are returned.

Comment: Pressacco, Thanks for the response. I got what you are saying but I am not understanding why the application is not loading the appname.exe.config itself....I am running the app via task scheduler

Comment: @NileshChandane : Maybe a permissions issue? Try running the application without the _Task Scheduler_.  Also, don't scheduled tasks have a "working directory"? Has this been set?

Answer (score 0):

this happens because your setting scope is set to `Application` rather than `user`

just open your *.settings file in visual studio and change the scope of your property to `user`

Comment: thank you! its working... Just to be sure, so whatever entries we have under application scope would not be able to change at RUNTIME, like after deployment of an app if I want to change lets say url,so I would not be able to change from the appname.exe.config if its define under Application scope ??

Comment: can you confirm above statement pls so that I can mark this as answer ?

Comment: not exactly. the idea is that when you set the setting scope to `Application` your application assumes that the settings file would be stored under the path `%appdata%\[CompanyName]\[AppName]\[version]\user.config`. but if you set the scope to `user` it assumes that it's stored at the same folder of the executable.